# Meaning of 惹人嫌?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

The full sentence is 唇上  唇下  留着  不长不短   但  总之   很   惹人嫌   的   髭须。 Which I've translated as 'His facial hair was not short or long, but overall the beard was suspicious. Is 'suspicious' a good translation of 惹人嫌 in this context? I've seen online dictionaries translate it as 'snot' which I just don't understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: submitting 惹人嫌 to online dictionaries, e.g. iciba will
supply possible choices, http://www.iciba.com/%E6%83%B9%E4%BA%BA%E5%AB%8C (causing displeasure, hideous, (people) cannot (are unable to) stand)

Comment: One word: annoying.

Answer (score 3):

惹: makes something happen

人: other people

嫌: 嫌弃 dislike, antipathy

惹人嫌的髭须 means creepy beard

---

惹人 = 令人 = making other people ...

惹人爱

惹人怜

惹人疼 (not pain, 疼爱)

Answer (score 1):

I think the translation is not good.
In this sentence, it described that one has long beards, so maybe it very messes in some others' view. So the meaning of 惹人嫌 should be "making other people dislike this person" in which the 嫌 has the same meaning in 嫌弃,

Certainly, the meaning is not "suspicious" (怀疑).

Answer (score 0):

唇上唇下留着不长不短但总之很惹人嫌的髭须。

Above his lips was a moustache and below was a beard, both neither long nor short, but both very ugly.

(Why is 'in a word' never 1 word? It's a mystery!)